# No accessor to set property private final java.util.Map org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONObject.nameValuePairs

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I'm trying to use Mongo DB for one of Java application using Spring boot. I have created model for my document and then using Mongo Repository and then trying to use JSONObject as one of the property in my document. While inserting a document into the collection works fine but while trying to access it I'm getting the exception. Below is my code please let me know if I'm making any mistake. Thanks in advance.

```
@Document(collection="AppSetting")
public class AppSetting {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String name;
    private JSONObject value;


    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the value
     */
    public JSONObject getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    /**
     * @param value the value to set
     */
    public void setValue(JSONObject value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface AppSettingRepository extends MongoRepository<AppSetting, ObjectId>{
    AppSetting findByName(String name);
}
```

Finally the service where I'm performing the operation is goes here:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/apidoc/appsetting")
public class AppSettingController {

    @Autowired
    AppSettingRepository appRepo;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/updateConnector/{appname}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> updateAvailableConnector(@PathVariable("appname") final String appName,
            @RequestBody final Map<String, String> connectors
    ) {

        if( connectors == null || appName == null) {
            return null;
        }

        AppSetting setting = appRepo.findByName(appName);


        if(setting == null) {
            setting = new AppSetting();
            setting.setName(appName);
        }

        if(setting.getValue() == null)
            setting.setValue(new JSONObject());

        // Update Existing Connectors
        for( String key : connectors.keySet()) {
            try {
                setting.getValue().put(key, connectors.get(key));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        appRepo.save(setting);
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No accessor to set property private final java.util.Map org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONObject.nameValuePairs!
    at org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONObject_Accessor_ao0wv9.setProperty(Unknown Source) ~[spring-boot-configuration-processor-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ConvertingPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ConvertingPropertyAccessor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:380) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.populateProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:297) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:277) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:247) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1493) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1391) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:380) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.populateProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:297) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:277) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:247) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:196) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:192) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:80) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ProjectingReadCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:3081) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2687) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2441) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ExecutableFindOperationSupport$ExecutableFindSupport.doFind(ExecutableFindOperationSupport.java:214) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ExecutableFindOperationSupport$ExecutableFindSupport.oneValue(ExecutableFindOperationSupport.java:126) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.lambda$getExecution$4(AbstractMongoQuery.java:126) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:99) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.11.RELEASE.jar:2.1.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.findByName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.adobe.apidoccreator.api.AppSettingController.updateAvailableConnector(AppSettingController.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.26.jar:9.0.26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]
```

Comment: Can you add whole error stacktrace here?

Comment: Added Stack trace

Comment: Can  you try using Map insteadOf JSONObject in your Entity?

Comment: Already tried, but while inserting any element into map it converts the key into Hashcode but I need the exact string as key.

Comment: Also using JSONObject I can store any kind of settings into the Object.

Comment: Getting same issue, how did you fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using Lombok. Once I removed Lombok and created Getters &  Setters as well as Constructors it worked.